# Disabling or Blocking access to Chrome's Task Manager

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions

Using a Chromebook. Stable channel.

After spending too much on distractive websites and loosing my focus on work... I would like to know a way do disable or block access to the Chrome browser's task manager. Since I want to disable all images, javascript and plugins on the entire Internet, except sites I whitelist (which is possible on Chrome's settings).

Using a Chrome extension, I could block access to the settings page with a password (which I would create and then throw away). Thus, changing back my preferences would be impossible after they are set. However, by opening the Task Manager from Chrome and ending this extension process, I was able to bypass and disable/uninstall any extensions.

Any help will do. Even switching to the Developer Mode If needed.

I am using Chrome OS. Not running Windows. So I am limited to Chrome browser only.

I need to get rid of the task manager.

Comment: Anything you can do (as an adminstrator) you can also undo. So the only real answer to this question is self-control.

Comment: Offers for payment for answering are not welcome on the [SE] network.

Comment: `So the only real answer to this question is self-control` - Maybe in this specific case, but Chrome's task-manager is a big issue that companies and such would need to deal with. The wording of this question is specific to the OP, but the problem isn't.